# How to make Python program run on Mac?

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to find out how to make Python program work on Mac computer. I've built a program using many `Python` modules like `lxml`,`selenium` etc. (`PhantomJS.exe`) and I've created an `exe` file using **Py2Exe** which works correctly but now, I've realised that it should be able to be executed on `Mac`. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: All Macs have Python installed already.

Comment: Macs cannot run `.exe` files. You'll likely need the source files that were used to _create_ the `.exe` file, which you can simply run with the built-in Python interpreter on the command line.

Comment: Make sure those modules are installed on your Mac, and execute the original python script. You don't have to make an executable fie.

Comment: Yeah, but depends which Python version (in my case 2.7.10) and which modules are used there. Besides that, the program/script uses PhantomJS.exe which could be problem since OSx doesn't use exe.

Comment: Ultimately, your `.exe` isn't going to run on your Mac. You need the `.py` files that were used to create it - simply run `python main.py`, where `main.py` is the file containing the entry point (`__main__`?) to your program.

Comment: I have made PhantomJS work on Mac, all you do is point it at the location, ex. `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('your file location here')`

Answer (score 1):

There is a mac alternative of py2exe, called [py2app](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/).

Comment: @Milano Get them to install the Mac version of PhantomJS